# The importance of the return keyword in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I want to understand how to use the return keyword with function properly and when to use it.

For instance, I tried the following code

```
function getWaterBottle(money) {
  console.log(`You Can Buy "${parseInt(money / 1.5)}" Bottles Of Water`)
  
  return money % 1.5;
}

getWaterBottle(4)
```

Then I thought to omit the return and add the same output to the console without the return keyword.

```
function getWaterBottle(money) {
  console.log(`You Can Buy "${parseInt(money / 1.5)}" Bottles Of Water`)

  console.log(`The change is ${money % 1.5}`) // this is the replacement of the return keybord

}

getWaterBottle(4)
```

So, my question is, what is the difference when using the return keyword and without it, and how and when to use it properly?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You're probably confused about how the Chrome console logs things. Chrome logs whatever value you give it. In your first example, it logs the return value automatically since that's what the expression evaluates to. The difference is obvious, your second function doesn't return anything, so no one else can access the result of the function. Javascript functions are very well documented, I don't think this is an appropriate question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Returning data from functions is a such an important concept in any programming language that you should stop where you are and take a moment to assess the situation. Your question itself reveals that you are can tinker with code but don’t know much about programming in general. Take a couple hours and run through the JavaScript beginner lessons on MDN or W3Schools. You’ll set yourself up for a good start. Happy coding 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` in Javascript is called a **statement**. Its role is to return a value to the calling function. Some functions may not return a value, so the `return` statement is not mandatory, it depends on what you are looking to do. No code after a `return` statement is executed. It is possible to use multiple `return` in a function when we use multiple `if` statement for example.

You may use the `return` statement in a particular situation, since variables declared inside your `getWaterBottle()` have a restricted scope to the body of the function, they are not visible from outside this function. To share the value of a variable declared inside your function to the calling function you use the `return` statement.

The value returned by the `return` statement can be assigned to a variable.

For example, let use your code, in the following code you are calculating the change, but you are not using it. You are just displaying in the console the number of bottles you can buy with the money you have. The change is actually returned, but not used. We can use it in a variable for example:

```js
    function getWaterBottle(money) {
        console.log(`You Can Buy "${parseInt(money / 1.5)}" Bottles Of Water`)
    
        return money % 1.5;
    
    }
    
    //We assign the returned value by the return statement to the variable that we name "change"
    let change = getWaterBottle(4)
    //We display the value of the variable in the console
    console.log(`The change is ${change}`);
```

This example is to make you understand how we can share the result of a function with the `return` statement

In another hand, you can use its value without assigning it to a variable, for example, we want to apply a discount to customers buying more than three bottles:

```js
function getWaterBottle(money) {
    //We return the number of bottles the customer can buy
    return parseInt(money / 1.5)
}

//We use an "if" statement, as you can see, the getWaterBottle() function is returning a value that can be read directly by the "if" statement.
let money = 5
if (getWaterBottle(money) > 3) {
    console.log("Eligible to a discount");
}
else {
    console.log("Not eligible to a discount");
}
```

Now, to show you the use of multiple `return` statement, lets take the previous discount example:

```js
function getWaterBottle(money) {
    //We assign the number of bottles the customer can buy to a variable
    numberOfBottles = parseInt(money / 1.5)

    //we check for the discount
    if (numberOfBottles > 3) {

        return true
    }
    else {

        return false
    }
}


//In this "if" statement, we check if the getWaterBottle() is returning true or famse
if (getWaterBottle(8)) {
    console.log("eligible to a discount");
}
else {
    console.log("not eligible to a discount");
}
```

Again, these are examples, according to your project, the code can be made shorter with some good practice.

About your second code, not using the `return` statement means that the code inside your function is executed, but no value is returned, in fact it returns `undefined` and even if you declare variables inside it, you can not use them outside your function.

Answer (score 2):

here is the different between your two example

with `return`:

```js
function getWaterBottle(money) {
  console.log("console.log inside function:", `You Can Buy "${parseInt(money / 1.5)}" Bottles Of Water`)
  
  return money % 1.5;
}

const dataFromFunction = getWaterBottle(4);

console.log("console.log outside function:", "data from function: " + dataFromFunction)
```

without `return`:

```js
function getWaterBottle(money) {
  console.log("console.log inside function:", `You Can Buy "${parseInt(money / 1.5)}" Bottles Of Water`);

  console.log("console.log inside function:", `The change is ${money % 1.5}`);

}

const dataFromFunction = getWaterBottle(4);

console.log("console.log outside function:","data from function: " + dataFromFunction)
```

without `return` in second example, the `dataFromFunction` is `undefined`. the `return` keyword will return whatever you write right after the keyword to the caller. find out more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Answer (score 2):

The `return` keyword is not just a keyword but one of the most basic and fundamental concepts of computer programming.

I want to store a value of the results of a calculation. I do that calculation with a `function` and store the result returned.

For a pure function the important part is that the function does nothing on its own. It should take some values as arguments, perform a calculation, then return the results with no side effects.

In other words, calling a pure function without doing anything with the return value should be the same as not calling the function at all.

The log statements don’t change the state of your program so those are still pure functions. They just don’t do anything  except read data and display it in the console.

Which in the end is the same as not being called when it comes to the actual state of your program.

Comment: I like that this answer communicates the importance of the return keyword beyond JavaScript. 

I don’t think it needs to go into details about pure functions, however. Someone at this stage of learning has a long way to go until those topics. Not to mention that the IO functions aren’t *really* pure.

Comment: @deadbird11 true. I’ve been at this for awhile so I didn’t realize how far off I’d gone into the weeds there lol